# In C#, how can I know the value I keyed in NumericUpDown been changed cause it out of boundary?

Tags: c#, numericupdown

I use a pair of NumericUpDowns in my program: num_Max and num_Min.
And use Validating change boundary of them.

```
private void num_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e){
    if((sender as NumericUpDown) == num_min)
num_max.Minimum = num_min.Value;
if((sender as NumericUpDown) == num_max)
num_min.Maximum = num_max.Value;
}
```

I want to show message "Value has been changed cause out of range!" when num_max.Minimum = 10 and user input 7. How can I do it?

Comment: You should surely set the min/max before people start playing with your numericupdown.  not during the validating process, then it would handle it for you

Comment: The min/max is work. I want to know if num_max.Minimum = 10, User input 7, NumericUpDown changed it to 10. I want to know User is input 7 not 10.

Comment: Then dont set the min/max so they can type what they want and validate, before you cancel the validation you will have the current value

Comment: So I need change the value by myself?

Comment: @H.C. you might need a derived class that overrides `ParseEdit` as this is the method responsible for checking the values. See [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.parseedittext(v=vs.110).aspx) However if you use the NumUpDowns to define the Max/Min for your application why would these have boundaries themselves in the first place? Smells like a problem in your architecture.

Comment: Under the method i described yes, but it lets you tell what they entered.

Comment: @MarkusDeibel Any idea how to design items which controls the upper / lower boundaries in system? Normally the upper boundary need >= the lower boundary.

Comment: @BugFinder I will try this method, thank you.